# Can I v-model input that is child of child (don't know how to ask)

Tags: vuejs2

I have this:

Login.vue has child FormGroup.vue
FormGroup.vue has two children - Input.vue and Label.vue

I have data() in Login.vue and how to v-model data from Input.vue that's inside FormGroup.vue?

Comment: By using `this.$ref`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use template refs to access data/methods of child component. For example in Login you can access FormGroup by adding a `ref` attribute and accessing it as:

```
<form-group ref="FormGroup" />
 
this.$refs.FormGroup
```

And then going further down it can be

```
<label ref="Label" />
<input ref="Input" />

this.$refs.FormGroup.$refs.Input
this.$refs.FormGroup.$refs.Label
```

But be careful before using `$refs` the child component must be rendered or else it will be null. It happens when there is a condition v-if on child components or the element is waiting for an API to complete.

Check: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html